# anguillajs web 8 override ribbon buttons method for enable/disable

Tags: core-service, cme

I am having issue try to enable and disable those Ribbon button but the "disableRibbonControlsForCommand" like undefined.

Tridion.RTFExtensions.disableRibbonControlsForCommand = function (command, state) {
   //my code here[image]
}

Comment: Please verify the configuration and update new namespace